# User input code returning incorrect responses

Tags: python-3.x

I am teaching my students some simple code in Python 3, and we are using if/elif/else statements along with user input to write simple "Choose Your Own Adventure" stories. The first time I wrote this code, it ran as expected. Now, it always delivers the first option no matter the input entered. Can anyone explain why this is? Thank you! THANKS, EVERYONE! MY PROBLEM HAS BEEN SOLVED.

```
cave=input('Would you like to enter the cave? Answer Y or N')

if cave == ('Y') or ('y'):
    print('The cave is cold.')
elif cave == ('N') or ('n'):
    print('Stay in the sunshine. Safe, but boring.')
else:
    print('That was not one of the choices.') 

tool= input ("You have two items in your bag: a torch and a sandwich. 
Which would you like to use?")
if tool == ("torch"):
    print ("The fire ignites the deadly gas that has built up in the 
cave. You die.")
elif tool ==("sandwich"):
    print ("Good idea. You'll need strength to explore the cave.")
else:
    print ("Why do you insist on making things difficult?")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - if statement not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026735/python-if-statement-not-working-correctly)

Comment: `cave == ('Y') or ('y')` evaluates as `(cave == 'Y') or True`, which is always `True`.

Comment: BTW , if I say 'N' and then 'Torch', why would I die if I'm not in the cave ?

Answer (score 0):

It's ambiguous for calculating is it True or False for this statement

```
if cave == ('Y') or ('y'):
```

it should be

```
if cave == ('Y') or cave == ('y'):
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, there isn't "multiple equation checks". When you want to create it, you should use something like this:

```
if a == b or a == c:
    #some code here...
```

You can also use **in**:

```
if a in (b, c):
    #some code here...
```

or

```
if a in [b, c]:
    #more code...
```

(This is a bit slower, so in games I recommend the first)